# Table not created in H2 database using spring tool suite @Entity is not working as intended

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, h2

[This is the H2 Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOHvY.png)
I'm a rookie trying to learn spring boot from youtube. I've been following a step by step process from a channel to connect a db in spring boot. So the problem is The name and Id part in my User.java file is not created here even after using @Entity and @Id.I'm not able to do it even after replicating the same steps. Can somebody explain what I'm missing.

This is my Application.java file

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DbApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is my User.java file

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Id;



@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    public String toString() {
        return name+ " : " + id ;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is my Controller file

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserDAO userdao;
    
    @RequestMapping("index")
    public String user() {
        return "index.jsp";
    }
    @RequestMapping("addUser")
    public String addUser(User user) {
        userdao.save(user);
        return "index.jsp";
    }
    @RequestMapping("getUser")
    public ModelAndView getUser(@RequestParam int id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("showUser.jsp");
        User user = userdao.findById(id).orElse(null);
        mav.addObject(user);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled= true
spring.datasource.platform= h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.manigandan</groupId>
    <artifactId>DB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>DB</name>
    <description>demo website</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.7</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What does UserDao look like? Set a break point at userdao.save(user) to see that user has an Id and name.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want to let Spring Boot create a database table according to the implemented entity *User*. The table should be named USER and should have two columns: ID and NAME.

Current application.properties are

```
spring.h2.console.enabled= true
spring.datasource.platform= h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Please use this instead

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa  
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.h2.console.enabled= true    
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Comment: I've tried this but now i'm getting whitelabel error page instead of the console

Comment: Please share the application log during startup.